# How to create a route with optional url var using gorilla mux?

Tags: go, mux

I want to have an optional URL variable in route. I can't seem to find a way using mux package. Here's my current route:

```
func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/view/{id:[0-9]+}", MakeHandler(ViewHandler))
    http.Handle("/", r)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

It works when the url is `localhost:8080/view/1`. I want it to accept even if there's no `id` so that if I enter `localhost:8080/view` it'll still work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define a new `HandleFunc` for the root `/view` path:

```
r.HandleFunc("/view", MakeHandler(RootHandler))
```

And have the `RootHandler` function do whatever you require for that path.

Answer (score 10):

Register the handler a second time with the path you want:

```
r.HandleFunc("/view", MakeHandler(ViewHandler))
```

Just make sure when you are getting your vars that you check for this case:

```
vars := mux.Vars(r)
id, ok := vars["id"]
if !ok {
  // directory listing
  return
}
// specific view
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `?` character to indicate that the `id:[0-9]+` pattern is optional, and handle whenever there is an `id` is passed or not in your `ViewHandler` function.

`main`:

```
func main() {
  r := mux.NewRouter()
  r.HandleFunc("/view/{id:[0-9]+?}", MakeHandler(ViewHandler))
  http.Handle("/", r)
  http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

`ViewHandler`:

```
func ViewHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  vars := mux.Vars(r)
  id := vars["id"]
  if id == "" {
      fmt.Println("there is no id")
  } else {
      fmt.Println("there is an id")
  }
}
```