# Handle Gorilla mux empty variable

Tags: go, gorilla

I'm using gorilla mux to get pattern values. How do I handle an empty variable like so:

Go:

```
func ProductHandler (w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    vars := mux.Vars(r)
    a := vars["key"]
    if a = "" {       //does not seem to register empty string
       //do something
    } else 
       //do something
}

var r = mux.NewRouter()

func main() {
    r.HandleFunc("/products/{key}", ProductHandler)

    http.Handle("/", r)

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

When I type the url www.example.com/products or www.example.com/products/ I get a 404 page not found error. How do i handle an empty variable in ProductHandler?

http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a route with optional url var using gorilla mux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503189/how-to-create-a-route-with-optional-url-var-using-gorilla-mux)

Comment: @SvenGrosen you're not supposed to write that by hand. When you cast a close-vote because of duplication, it's automatically posted for you :P

Comment: @tomwilde I didn't write it by hand, just flagged it.

Comment: Weird. Maybe they changed the system but I can only see one my own vote. I'll post on meta.

Answer (score 3):

Simplest solution? Add:

```
r.HandleFunc("/products", ProductHandler)
```

I am pretty sure Gorilla will route <s>the longest match</s> in order of registration.

This is also the way the [documentation's overview page](http://www.gorillatoolkit.org/pkg/mux#overview) suggest it be used:

> Then register routes in the subrouter:
>
> ```
> s.HandleFunc("/products/", ProductsHandler)
> s.HandleFunc("/products/{key}", ProductHandler)
> s.HandleFunc("/articles/{category}/{id:[0-9]+}"), ArticleHandler)
> ```